# Pandas: ignore null values when using .astype(str)?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

So I have a dataframe, call it `TABLE` and I'm using Pandas with Python 2.7 to analyze it. It's mostly categorical data so right now my goal is to have a summary of my table where I list each column name and the average length of the values in that column.
Example table:

```
   A      B     C    E    F
0  djsdd  973  348f  NaN  abcd
1  dsa    49   34h5  NaN  NaN
```

Then my desired output would be something like:

```
Column AvgLength
A      4.0
B      2.5
C      4.0
E      NaN
F      4.0
```

Now the first problem I had was that there are some numerical values in the dataset. I thought I could resolve that by using `.astype(str)` so I did the following:

```
for k in TABLE:
    print "%s\t %s"%(k,TABLE[k].astype(str).str.len().mean())
```

The issue now is that it looks to me like `.astype(str)` is converting the null values to strings because I ended up with the following output:

```
Column AvgLength
A      4.0
B      2.5
C      4.0
E      3.0
F      3.5
```

Notice that column E containing the null values is giving me an average length of 3, and column F is giving me an average of 3.5. My understanding is this happened because it's taking the length of the string "NaN."

Is there some way to do what I want and ignore the Null values? Or is there a completely different approach I should be taking (I'm very new to pandas)?

(I did read about `.dropna()` but I don't want to omit all columns that might contain null values because some columns may have null values alongside data. I want to just ignore the null values from my mean).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stack` to get series
`dropna` to get rid of `NaN`
`astype(str).str.len()` to get lengths
`unstack().mean()` for average length
`reindex(TABLE.columns)` to ensure we get all original columns represented

```
TABLE.stack().dropna().astype(str).str.len().unstack().mean().reindex(TABLE.columns)

A    4.0
B    2.5
C    4.0
E    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I thought that `dropna` would drop the entire column if any null values were found in it? I don't want to drop an entire column because sometimes a column may contain both data and null values. I've edited my original question to include this case.

Comment: Try my solution.  I take care of that with the `reindex` and even say so in the post.  My solution works for your updated post as well.

Comment: Ya I see that now. I'll have to look into how `stack` works. Thanks!

Comment: So just to add, I was just reading up on how `stack` works. It looks like I can omit the `.dropna()` from the solution you gave because `stack` includes `dropna=True` as a default parameter. I tried it out and it still gave the correct results.